# How do I construct a proper list?

Tags: equations

I want to do something like this:

`1. blah blah blah`

`2. blah blah blah`

`3. blah blah blah`

How do I do this?

Comment: We don't typically refer to that as a set of equations, but instead, a list. See what `\begin{enumerate} \item blah blah blah \item blah blah blah \item blah blah blah \end{enumerate}` gives you...

Comment: @Werner I tested this with `\begin{enumerate} \item \square P \item P \rightarrow Q \item P \leftarrow Q \end{enumerate}`, but I got [this result.](https://i.imgur.com/THNcyPO.jpg)

Comment: You need to place math-related content in math mode (between `$`...`$`). With `\begin{enumerate}
  \item $\square P$
  \item $P \rightarrow Q$
  \item $P \leftarrow Q$
\end{enumerate}` I get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ec6V.png). If you don't please provide a minimal example as part of your question so we can attempt to replicate your current issue.

Comment: If what you want, though, is numbered equations, you should use the `equation` environment, or similar. `\begin{equation} \square P \end{equation} \begin{equation} P \rightarrow Q \end{equation}` etc.

Comment: Frankly this is covered on the very first pages of *every* introduction to LaTeX. I strongly recommend that you read one of the resources here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner/ . If you have problems then please also consider http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that .

Comment: Downvoters, please let the comments suffice to help a new user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to keep issues related to the specifics of mathematical formulas separate from other aspects of the document, such as the use of an enumerated list of items to provide a visual (as well as numerical) sequence for the way some argument is being laid out to the readers.

I think the following may be what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for "\square" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate} % start an enumerated list
\item $\square P$
\item $P\to Q$
\item $P\gets Q$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Observe that the *body* of each enumerated item is a math formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcounter{eq}
\setcounter{eq}{1}
\newcommand{\eq}{{\noindent {\arabic{eq}}} \addtocounter{eq}{1}{\hspace{-0.1cm{{.}}}} }
\newcommand{\eqz}{{\setcounter{eq}{1}} {{\arabic{eq}}} \addtocounter{eq}{1}\hspace{-0.1cm{{.}}}}

\begin{document}
\eq Bla
\eq bla bla
\eq bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume you want a `\par` before the `\noindent` instruction? By the way, what is the `\eqz` macro supposed to accomplish? The reason I ask is that it doesn't appear to be used in your MWE. Finally, if one ever needs to cross-reference one of these items, one should use `\refstepcounter{eq}` instead of `\addtocounter{eq}{1}`.